# Dependency property for buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I'm trying to create a boolean property for Buttons called '`IsVisibleWhenReadOnly`'.  I want this to be used on buttons in a StackPanel, so they can be visible or not depending on whether the data is in a `ReadOnly` state.  Ie when in `ReadOnly` state, Save and Cancel buttons are Hidden, but the Edit button is Visible. When the Edit button is clicked the `ReadOnly` state becomes false and the Cancel and Save buttons become Visible and the Edit button is Hidden.

My property code:

```
public bool IsVisibleWhenReadOnly
{
  get { return (bool)GetValue(IsVisibleWhenReadOnlyProperty); }
  set { SetValue(IsVisibleWhenReadOnlyProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsVisibleWhenReadOnly.
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsVisibleWhenReadOnlyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("IsVisibleWhenReadOnly",
                                 typeof(bool), 
                                 typeof(Button), 
                                 new PropertyMetadata(true));
```

Button style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <Setter Property="Visibility">
    <Setter.Value>
      <Binding Path="IsVisibleWhenReadOnly" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}" Mode="OneWay">
        <Binding.Converter>
          <utils:BoolToVisibilityConverter/>
        </Binding.Converter>
      </Binding>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

and button code:

```
<Button Name="btnEdit" Content="Edit" MinWidth="75" Height="25" 
    Click="btnEdit_Click" IsVisibleWhenReadOnly="true" />
```

`IsReadOnly` is another dependency property that is happily working, and enables/disables controls based on its value, but I want this to affect visibility, not enabledness.

Unfortunately, I'm getting three errors on compilation:

```
The member "IsVisibleWhenReadOnly" is not recognized or is not accessible.
The property 'IsVisibleWhenReadOnly' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'.
The property 'IsVisibleWhenReadOnly' was not found in type 'Button'.
```

I'm guessing it is in the `typeOf(Button),` line, but changing that to 'BaseWindow' (which is the `typeOf()` value for my 'IsReadOnly' property) didn't make a difference.  I'm also pretty sure my BoolToVisibilityConverter isn't the problem.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong and point me in the right direction?

Edit:  I'd like to use the Dependency Property with more than just Buttons, if possible.  Eg, StackPanels, CheckBoxes, etc, so a solution that isn't restricted to just Buttons is the ideal.

Comment: Where did you implement the `DependencyProperty`? Did you extend the `Button` class?

Comment: The DP is implemented in BaseWindow.cs which all my Windows inherit.  I haven't extended Button - I didn't see this instruction when reading on DPs.

Comment: Well then you have to use an `AttachedProperty` as the answers are already illustrating.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using an [attached dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597495.aspx) if you want to piggy back onto an existing control. So something like:

```
public static void SetIsVisibleWhenReadOnly(UIElement element, bool value)
{
    element.SetValue(IsVisibleWhenReadOnlyProperty, value);
}
public static bool GetIsVisibleWhenReadOnly(UIElement element)
{
    return (bool)element.GetValue(IsVisibleWhenReadOnlyProperty);
}
// Using a Registerd DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsVisibleWhenReadOnly.
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsVisibleWhenReadOnlyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsVisibleWhenReadOnly",
                                     typeof(bool),
                                     typeof(Button),
                                     new PropertyMetadata(true));
```

I would also consider a multi-binding for the visibility converter so you have access to IsReadOnly and IsVisibileWhenReadOnly when determining the Visiblity value to return.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to register your `DependancyProperty` as an `AttachedProperty` and if you want to use it on other controls use `typeof(FrameworkElement)` instead of `typeof(Button)`

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty IsVisibleWhenReadOnlyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsVisibleWhenReadOnly"
     , typeof(bool), typeof(FrameworkElement),new PropertyMetadata(true));
```

But it may be a simpler idea to use a `DataTrigger`

Example:

```
<Button>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisibleWhenReadOnly}" Value="True" >
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: I made it an AttachedProperty, and tried it with and without using a DataTrigger.  The 3rd exception has stopped, but I am still getting the other two.  Is there more to AttachedProperties than 'RegisterAttached'?  Or am I missing something else?

Comment: Dont think so, I tested the code above before posting and all worked fine.